# Manually inflate items in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, lag, layout-inflater

I have two views. A big view (with a picture) and a RecyclerView below. When you start scrolling the top view will shrink and make space for the recyclerview below - like this:

[Scroll down to the "Flexible space with image" example](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/scrolling-techniques.html#scrolling-techniques-scrolling)

Everything work nice....almost. The one issue I have is that if you initially scroll really fast you will get some lag. This is because the RecyclerView only have inflated 2 or 3 items, but need to inflate a lot more when you scroll. Once all the views are inflated (and in the cache) everything is very smooth. Also if you scroll back to the top position and try to repeat.

Is there someway I can make my recyclerview inflate some more items (at startup) even if they are not visible. The default implementation only seems to inflate 1 extra (hidden) item

Thanks

Comment: The lag is probably caused by loading of data on UI thread. If you move it to [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), lag should disappear.

Comment: @Vojtaaa9 It's not. All data is loaded in the background and I can see from the profiler that it's the inflation of layouts which is the problem

Comment: Maybe your row layout is too heavy, can you post your Row layout for RecyclerView?